# How to group rows without using GROUP BY clause

Tags: postgresql, t-sql, grouping, window-functions

Let's say I have simple table:

```
   Date          Price
-----------------------
2012-01-05        23
2015-04-08        145
2016-03-09        12
2015-09-09        87
2000-01-15        23
2016-01-15        89
2016-07-12        23
2012-04-08        65
```

I want to group this rows by year but without using GROUP BY clause. It would be good if I could add another column that would contain year or character that would indicate group, like this:

```
Date          Price     Group
-------------------------------
2012-01-05        23      1
2015-04-08        145     2
2016-03-09        12      3
2015-09-09        87      2
2000-01-15        23      4
2016-01-15        89      3
2016-07-12        23      3
2012-04-08        65      1
```

I tried use over() clause but to be honest I don't know which function use with over().

Comment: `select *, extract(year from Date) as Group from table;` ?

Comment: Ehhh I am embarrassed because it's brilliant and so...simple ;s

Comment: As a rule the PostgreSQL and TSQL tags are incompatible. Are you in need of a solution that works for both?

Comment: No, thanks. I already dealt with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combination of extract year from date and dense_rank will do the trick

```
select *,
dense_rank ()  OVER(order by extract(year from Date))
from YOURTABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do the CASE if you only want to add another column

```
SELECT DATE, 
       PRICE,
  CASE DATE_PART('YEAR', DATE) WHEN 2015 THEN 1 
                               WHEN 2016 THEN 2 ... END


FROM MYTABLE
```

But if you want to get the aggregate of something then you do OVER() or GROUP BY

Comment: In PostgreSQL it should be `date_part('year', Date)` Also it is shorter: `case date_part('year', date) when 2015 then 1 when 2016 then 2 ... end`

Comment: @Abelisto Thanks, I made edits, didn't realize the question was for Postgre